# Bradford networks persistent agent windows 8.1

Tags: networking

My college requires Bradford networks persistent agent. I am running Win8.1 Pro, and AVG 2014. I run the scan and it says "pc not passed requirements" any fixes?

Seems like bradford does not support 8.1...

Comment: Contact your University's IT Helpdesk, problems like this are why they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Change your browser user agent. Use firefox and install the User Agent Switcher plugin. Change the user agent to an iPhone.